# Is there a way to get the same result from Cognitive Services - Read API always?

Tags: computer-vision, ocr, azure-cognitive-services

We have an image with two different read result in, with 2 weeks period of time between them.

1- How could this happened? is there a training that make result changed?

2- Is there any way to prevent the previous scenario from being happened again?

Answer (score 0):

Read API is deterministic unless there are updates in the backend. In your case, the two weeks period may happen to be when they are rolling out new backend engines.